# how to fill column in table with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

As usual in tables with ng-repeat fills rows, not columns. But in my case, unfortunately, response from server looks like:

```
[
       [{name:'John'},{name:'Sarah'},{name:'Ann'},{name:'Josh'},{name:'Mike'},{name:'Olaf'},{name:'Jane'},{name:'Rachel'},{name:'Hank'},{name:'Nick'}],
       [{age:'23'},{age:'41'},{age:'23'},{age:'14'},{age:'42'},{age:'32'},{age:'12'},{age:'65'},{age:'32'},{age:'21'}],
       [{sex:'female'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'male'}],
       [{eyes:'brown'},{eyes:'green'},{eyes:'blue'},{eyes:'blue'},{eyes:'grey'},{eyes:'green'},{eyes:'brown'},{eyes:'brown'},{eyes:'blue'},{eyes:'brown'}],
      ]
```

But I need names in their own column, age in their column etc. And when I try to use ng-repeat it repeats cells in rows, not columns.. How can I fill columns one by one, at first names, then ages, etc?

```js
angular.module('App', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.arr = [
       [{name:'John'},{name:'Sarah'},{name:'Ann'},{name:'Josh'},{name:'Mike'},{name:'Olaf'},{name:'Jane'},{name:'Rachel'},{name:'Hank'},{name:'Nick'}],
       [{age:'23'},{age:'41'},{age:'23'},{age:'14'},{age:'42'},{age:'32'},{age:'12'},{age:'65'},{age:'32'},{age:'21'}],
       [{sex:'female'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'male'}],
       [{eyes:'brown'},{eyes:'green'},{eyes:'blue'},{eyes:'blue'},{eyes:'grey'},{eyes:'green'},{eyes:'brown'},{eyes:'brown'},{eyes:'blue'},{eyes:'brown'}],
      ]
  });
```

```css
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-s6z2{text-align:center}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <table class="tg">
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-s6z2">name</th>
        <th class="tg-s6z2">age</th>
        <th class="tg-s6z2">sex</th>
        <th class="tg-s6z2">eyes color</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your requirement as per the JSON you given.

You can use the power of `ng-repeat` and use **`$index`** to get your solution done.

```js
angular.module('App', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.arr = [
       [{name:'John'},{name:'Sarah'},{name:'Ann'},{name:'Josh'},{name:'Mike'},{name:'Olaf'},{name:'Jane'},{name:'Rachel'},{name:'Hank'},{name:'Nick'}],
       [{age:'23'},{age:'41'},{age:'23'},{age:'14'},{age:'42'},{age:'32'},{age:'12'},{age:'65'},{age:'32'},{age:'21'}],
       [{sex:'female'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'male'}],
       [{eyes:'brown'},{eyes:'green'},{eyes:'blue'},{eyes:'blue'},{eyes:'grey'},{eyes:'green'},{eyes:'brown'},{eyes:'brown'},{eyes:'blue'},{eyes:'brown'}],
      ]
  });
```

```css
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-s6z2{text-align:center}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <table class="tg">
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-s6z2">name</th>
        <th class="tg-s6z2">age</th>
        <th class="tg-s6z2">sex</th>
        <th class="tg-s6z2">eyes color</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="a in arr[0]">
        <td class="tg-s6z2">{{a.name}}</td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2">{{arr[1][$index].age}}</td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2">{{arr[2][$index].sex}}</td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2">{{arr[3][$index].eyes}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

**PLEASE RUN THE ABOVE SNIPPET**

[**HERE IS A WORKING DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/l67E42oWnYMrmrpdjSNU?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://codepen.io/DaniloPolani/pen/BpMrvg

The logic is to iterate the array saving the index (with angular, you can do this with `track by $index`).

With that index, you can retrieve the correct array position for each property (`arr[0][$index].name`, where `arr[0]` is the array of names and `$index` the position of the current element). You can learn more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

But please edit your array, it's better (for code and eyes) make associative arrays with all params. So an array of array with eyes, name etc. together.

```
$scope.arr = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    eyes: 'brown'
  }
];
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my organization response from server has this view.. perhaps I can change it, but it undesirable :(

Comment: I imagined it, anyway I wish you can understand the code above!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to server to change format of your data (which would be the best solution), use custom function and format it properly in controller.

With `formatArray` you'll be able to use filters, such as orderBy, enable search feature, etc.

```js
angular.module('App', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.arr = [
       [{name:'John'},{name:'Sarah'},{name:'Ann'},{name:'Josh'},{name:'Mike'},{name:'Olaf'},{name:'Jane'},{name:'Rachel'},{name:'Hank'},{name:'Nick'}],
       [{age:'23'},{age:'41'},{age:'23'},{age:'14'},{age:'42'},{age:'32'},{age:'12'},{age:'65'},{age:'32'},{age:'21'}],
       [{sex:'female'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'female'},{sex:'male'},{sex:'male'}],
       [{eyes:'brown'},{eyes:'green'},{eyes:'blue'},{eyes:'blue'},{eyes:'grey'},{eyes:'green'},{eyes:'brown'},{eyes:'brown'},{eyes:'blue'},{eyes:'brown'}],
      ]


    var formatArray = function (arr) {
      var formated = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
          if (!formated[j] && formated.length === j) {
            formated.push({});
          }
          for (prop in arr[i][j]) {

            formated[j][prop] = arr[i][j][prop];
          }
        }
      }

      return formated;
    };

    $scope.formatedArray = formatArray($scope.arr);
  });
```

```css
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-s6z2{text-align:center}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <table class="tg">
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-s6z2">name</th>
        <th class="tg-s6z2">age</th>
        <th class="tg-s6z2">sex</th>
        <th class="tg-s6z2">eyes color</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in formatedArray">
        <td class="tg-s6z2" ng-bind="item.name"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2" ng-bind="item.age"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2" ng-bind="item.sex"></td>
        <td class="tg-s6z2" ng-bind="item.eyes"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```